# In AucTeX, new item in itemized list after comment results in commented next item

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

In AucTeX, when editing an itemized list:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item My item % note to self
\end{itemize}
```

when I do C-c C-j after 'self' I get:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item My item % note to self
 % \item
\end{itemize}
```

when I want:

```
\begin{itemize}
 \item My item % note to self
 \item
\end{itemize}
```

Is there a setting a can modify to make this work correctly?

Comment: Interesting... so the comment at the end of the previous line is causing the new line to be commented.

Comment: I think that's a known bug of AucTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(setq LaTeX-insert-into-comments nil)
```

seems to solve the problem, although it may have other effects that I'm not aware of. To use it, put it in your .emacs customization file; to test it, try `M-:` then paste the above code into the prompt.

The variable `LaTeX-insert-into-comments` is defined as

```
*Whether insertion commands stay in comments. 
This allows using the insertion commands even when
the lines are outcommented, like in dtx files.
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is something better:

```
(defadvice LaTeX-insert-item (around my-LaTeX-insert-item activate)
     (let  ((LaTeX-insert-into-comments nil)) ad-do-it))
```

This will prevent unwanted effects from setting the `LaTeX-insert-into-comments` globally to `nil` by changing it only temporarily when you insert an item. Again, to use it, put it in your .emacs customization file.